# .serialize() doesn't obtain the right textarea content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have precompiled some textareas inside a form. The text inside the textareas must be modified by the user and the sent by AJAX to another page. Something like:

1. Precompiled text: "this is the precompiled text "
2. User intervention: "this is the precompiled text with my intervention"
3. Click button and send form to ajax

This is the AJAX:

```
function send() {
  var data_form = $('#id_form').serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "another_page.php",
    data: data_form,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data) {
    },
    error: function() {
    }
  });
}
```

Problem is in `var data_form = $('#id_form').serialize();` it returns always the old text value ("this is the precompiled text ") and I lose the user intervention. Why this behaviour happening? Serialize does not get the actual values in the form elements?

EDIT

the function send() is called by the click on a button

```
<a href="#" id="" onclick="send();" >SEND</a>
```

A user click this button after he had modified the textarea contents.

Comment: Calling the `send()` function is a one-time execution. At the beginning, you're setting `data_form` to the serialized text of `$('#id_form)`. It will not automatically update the way you have structured your code.

Comment: We need to know when and how the `send()` function is called. Can you provide a better example? I suspect that you are serialising the form _before_ the `textarea` is updated but without seeing your code I can't tell.

Comment: i have edited my question

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mystake is to not consider tinymce.My textarea are managed by tinymce, it do not save directly the update inside a text area, i need to call `tinyMCE.triggerSave();` first.